# one-hot-encoding (dummy variables) with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

I would like to use BigQuery instead of Pandas to create dummy variables (one-hot-encoding) for my categories.
I will end up with about 200 columns, therefore I can't do it manually and hard code it

Test dataset (the actual one has many more variables than this one)

```
WITH table AS (
SELECT 1001 as ID, 'blue' As Color, 'big' AS size UNION ALL
SELECT 1002 as ID, 'yellow' As Color, 'medium' AS size UNION ALL
SELECT 1003 as ID, 'red' As Color, 'small' AS size UNION ALL
SELECT 1004 as ID, 'blue' As Color, 'small' AS size)

SELECT *
FROM table
```

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
DECLARE Colors, Sizes ARRAY<STRING>;

SET (Colors, Sizes) = (SELECT AS STRUCT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Color), ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT Size) FROM `project.dataset.table`);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
CREATE TEMP TABLE result AS  -- added line
SELECT ID, ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG("COUNTIF(Color = '" || Color || "') AS Color_" || Color ORDER BY Color)
  FROM UNNEST(Colors) AS Color
) || (
  SELECT ', ' || STRING_AGG("COUNTIF(Size = '" || Size || "') AS Size_" || Size ORDER BY Size)
  FROM UNNEST(Sizes) AS Size
) || '''
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
''';  -- added `;`

SELECT * FROM result;  -- added line
```

If to applied to sample data in your question - the output is as below

[image]

Comment: thanks. It doesn't return a table though, but a number of "jobs". how do I save the output as a table on bigquery?

Comment: sure, sorry - I thought this would be obvious to use in needed way. see update in my answer though. take a look to two added lines and one updated (they have respective comments so it is easy to identify them) :o)

Comment: sorry, maybe it's obvious but I didn't use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE before. Even after adding the new lines you've included, I still need to click on "view results" to see the table output. I want to automatically save the one hot encoded dataset

Comment: To save the results automatically you can change the settings in the query tab to persist to a table, please refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#permanent-table)